# How are operands promoted

Tags: c, promotions

I have the following code in C:

```
        int l;
        short s;

        l = 0xdeadbeef;
        s = l;
```

Assuming int is 32 bits and short is 16 bits, when performing s = l, s will be promoted to 32 bits and after assignment, only lower 16 bits will be kept in s. My question is that when s is promoted to 32 bits, will the additional 16 bits be set to 0x0 or 0xf ?

Source : http://www.phrack.com/issues.html?issue=60&id=10

Comment: What makes you think `s` is promoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `s` is not promoted at all. Since `s` is signed and `l` is too large to fit in `s`, assigning l to s in this case is implementation defined behavior.

> 6.3.1.3-3
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-deﬁned or an
>   implementation-deﬁned signal is raised.

Comment: @Jake I did. It looks confusing. All that "promotion" / "demotion" of s is unmentioned by the standards - it's an artificial explanation.

Comment: @Jake A Phrack article is always useful. You just have to take it with a bit of salt.

Answer (score 0):

Assembler have operation for moving **whole** register **or part** of it (`MOV EAX, 0`, `MOV AX, 0`, `MOV AL, 0` - respectively 32bits, 16bits, 8bits). As `short` is 16-bit integer `MOV AX, 0` form would be used, although, that depends on compiler implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're going to promote s to some wider type.
This depends on the destination type: whether it is signed or unsigned. If the destination type is signed there will be signed promotion done. Otherwise -- unsigned promotion. The signed promotion fills higher bits by 0 or 1 depending on the sign of the promoted value.